# Turn off network on Raspbian

Tags: linux, debian, networking

I'm trying to set up cron to turn off networking on my Raspberry Pi during the night (from 23:00 to 8:00).

The problem is that none of this commands do the job:

```
$ sudo service networking stop
$ sudo ifconfig eth0 down
$ sudo ifdown eth0
```

From the output it looks like the command worked but the interface is still up (I can `ping 8.8.8.8` and it's present in `ifconfig`).

This is the content of `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

auto wlan1
allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

output of `ifconfig` (masked MAC)

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  
          inet addr:192.168.1.102  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1545 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1054 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:117138 (114.3 KiB)  TX bytes:156391 (152.7 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1104 (1.0 KiB)  TX bytes:1104 (1.0 KiB)
```

output of `route -n`

```
Kernel IP routing table

Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
```

Any help?

Comment: Add `ipconfig` and `route -n` after you tried to disable networking to you question.

Comment: i've added them

Comment: After disabling they don't change

Comment: Can you please add the statements you've put in your `crontab`? I'm assuming that stopping networking outside of `cron` works fine, or can you still `ping 8.8.8.8` after `ifconfig eth0 down`? Also, which user's `crontab` were the commands in?

Comment: I'm not adding to crontab yet because it doesn't work normally.                               pi@RaspberryPi:~$ sudo ifconfig eth0 down [sudo] password for pi:  pi@RaspberryPi:~$ ping 8.8.8.8 PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data. 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=1 ttl=56 time=39.6 ms 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=2 ttl=56 time=39.4 ms ^C --- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics --- 2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 39.458/39.536/39.615/0.213 ms pi@RaspberryPi:~$

Answer (score 2):

Asked and solved in [Can't turn off network](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/33703/cant-turn-off-network#comment44003_33703).

```
# service ifplugd stop && ifconfig eth0 down
```

In [`cron`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cron.8.html), added through `sudo crontab -e`

```
0 23 * * * /usr/sbin/service ifplugd stop && /sbin/ifconfig eth0 down

0 8 * * * /usr/sbin/service ifplugd start && /sbin/ifconfig eth0 up
```